# Firebase data structure suggestions

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this data structure

```
{
"post": {
    "<postID>": {
        "postUserID": "<--uid-->",
        "postUserName": "Nicholas",
        "postUserIMG": "http://firebase.....",
        "postImage": "http://firebase.....",
        "Topic": "It is a nice day",
        "like": "0"
    }
},
"user": {
    "<--uid-->": {
        "username": "Nicholas",
        "profilePic": "http://firebase.....",
        "post": "<postID>"
    }
}
}
```

It work fine however I got some problems on the Post data. If I have change the user data(for example: username), I need to change all the post data for the user. I think this structure is not efficient at all. How to refactor the data structure so It can change the User data one time only.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be storing the user id and then getting the user if you need it's details via a second query with the user id from the post. I would recommend this data structure:

```
{
    "post" : {
        "<postID>" : {
            "postUserID" : "<--uid-->",
            "postImage" : "http://firebase.....",
            "Topic" : "It is a nice day",
            "like" : "0"
        }
    },
    "user" : {
        "<--uid-->" : {
            "username" : "Nicholas",
            "profilePic" : "http://firebase.....",
            "post" : "<postID>"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this out but it is not working since I display the post by the struct `Post` in table view. How could I do that?

Comment: You'll have to query each individual user and store it in another variable.